# Submit python dependencies into spark cluster

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Is there any proper way to submit complex dependencies into spark using python? I found following way while searching through the internet:

```
def import_pymystem3(x):
    import pymystem3
    return x

int_rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([1,2,3,4])
int_rdd.map(lambda x: import_pymystem3(x))
int_rdd.collect()
```

However, this way of accessing imports is inconvenient due to `map()` usage: accessing external library from inside `map()` disables usage of this import on other RDDs.

Apache documentation suggests `--py-files`, and this is how I do it:

Create dependencies.txt, listing all of the dependencies I use in, then

`sudo python36 -m pip install dependencies -r requirements.txt`

`sudo zip -r ../dependencies/zip .`

and finally `spark-submit --executor-memory 50g --driver-memory 50g --py-files [path to requirements.zip] [path to project.py]`

And this is what I see: `NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/home/.../dependencies/dependencies.zip/sklearn/__check_build'`

Moreover, other imports are not loaded as well: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nltk'`

Is there any working approach of submitting complex libraries into apache spark cluster using pyspark? All of the needed packages are installed on the worker nodes.

Answer (score 1):

You are installing the dependencies in the system (or environment). If you want to make a zip, you should indicate the target path. in the pip command,

This is your coded adapted:

```sh
# Sudo should not be needed
python36 -m pip install -t ./dependencies -r requirements.txt
zip -r dependencies.zip ./dependencies
```